# Choosing page depending on users choices

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a webpage where a user asked their name(textbox) and gender(radio buttons) on the front page.  This will then link to a new page will be dependent on whether they chose if they are male or female, it will also need to  display their name as entered in the text box.

So far I have the name part working using javascript this is on the front page with the form action directed to a new page:

```
// Called on form's `onsubmit`
    function tosubmit() {
        // Getting the value of your text input
        var mytext = document.getElementById("mytext").value;

        // Storing the value above into localStorage
        localStorage.setItem("mytext", mytext);

        return true;
    }
```

and this is on the other page:

```
// Called on body's `onload` event
function init() {
    // Retrieving the text input's value which was stored into localStorage
    var mytext = localStorage.getItem("mytext");

    // Writing the value in the document
    document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = mytext;
}
```

The main problem here is that this always directs to the same page.  Can anyone tell me how I could solve this problem and add in the option for a user to choose their gender and the next page would be dependant on this choice?

edit: This is my form

```
<form class="enter-name" name="myform" onsubmit="tosubmit();" action="page1.html">

        <input  id="mytext" type="text" name="data" placeholder="Enter name" maxlength="12">

        Male:  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" /><br />
        Female: <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" /><br />
        <input id="name-submit" type="submit" value="">

</form>
```

Comment: please dont tag spam, all you use above is javascript

Comment: How do you redirect to another page?

Comment: @Dagon Why is it spam? All tags are perfectly applicable to described problem.

Comment: there is no php or jquery or even html in the question

Comment: @Dagon Sorry, I tagged them as I thought jquery and php could be alternative ways of solving my problem

Comment: @dfsq in the form tag: <form class="enter-name" name="myform" onsubmit="tosubmit();" action="page1.html">

Comment: @Dagon But it doesn't mean that the question has nothing to do with PHP. jQuery shows that answer can use this library if needed. And HTML is implied probably, because there is a form submission.

Comment: So you want form to be submitted to page2.html in other case?

Comment: I want to add in the choice of gender then submit the form to either page1 or 2 depending on the users choice

Comment: So you just need to change form action depending on gender. If you added more HTML of how you set up a gender, I would give an example.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this with php - have the form post to a handler that will redirect based on the posted values. In this case the handler is in the same page:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['name'], $_POST['gender'])){

    $page = ($_POST['gender']=='male')? 'male-page.php' : 'female-page.php';
    header('Location:'.$page.'?name='.$_POST['name']);
    die();
}
?>

<html>
    <head><!-- head stuff here--></head>
    <body>
        <form class="enter-name" name="myform" action="" method="post">

            <input  id="mytext" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter name" maxlength="12">

            Male:  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" /><br />
            Female: <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" /><br />
            <input id="name-submit" type="submit" value="">

        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

in the redirected to page, you can access name via the query string parameter in php:

```
<div id="name">
    <?php echo $_GET['name'];?>
</div>
```

Comment: That's great Steve. Thanks.  How would I then use the name in the other page in the same way I am currently using it with getElementByID and innerHTML to put the name inside a chosen id?

Comment: Appreciate the help.  For some reason it isn't redirecting me to the chosen page. It's just reloading the same page when I click submit

Comment: Oops, you need to give your input the name `'name'`, currently it is named `'data'`

Comment: Hmm, perhaps you need to make the url absolute: `header('Location:/'.$page.'?name='.$_POST['name']);` note the forward slash